# Handle time from different timezone and store into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I making a website with facebook,
the bad thing is.. there is too many timezone and hard to convert into UTC. 
my server is using UTC as default setting, 
may i know how could i manage it in more generic way, to convert difference time zone into UTC time, and display it into preset timezone setting ?

additionally, may i know how could i store this into mysql database with php ?

2011-04-10T08:13:30+0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gmdate()` function, it formats the time in UTC.

Comment: @ummar , do you know how to let mysql store this 2011-04-10T08:13:30+0000 ? THX

Comment: @Spencer Lim, some Mysql geek will describe it better, however I think DATETIME field will do this job.. give it a try..

Comment: @ummar, tried gmdate whether it will convert automatically or not but failed... is that possible to take off the t and change : to - also remove +0000  ? if i want to do this in php ? this is what come into my idea but i'm not skill in this field =.=

Comment: @Spencer Lim, Why `gmdate()` didn't work? any how this code will do what you want to do `$str = "2011-04-10T08:13:30+0000";
 $str = str_ireplace("t"," ",$str);
 $str = str_ireplace(":","-",$str); //$str will contain 2011-04-10 08-13-30+0000
 $str = substr($str,0,strlen($str)-5);
 print $str; //will print 2011-04-10 08-13-30`

Comment: @ummar, wow... Thx god and Thx ummar =D i though it will do everything but just gmdate("r", "the time")... haha, i'm new in php and finally i can do it now XD Thx again ^^